# Forcing Mercurial to automatically commit on remote side before a pull

Tags: mercurial

I'm a web developer. I have a Testing server which is remote and accessible by several people (designer, clients,). I would like to setup a workflow where I can locally pull changes from the Testing server over SSH, with Mercurial automatically committing any changes that may have happened remotely before it executes the pull. These changes might include files uploaded through the CMS or stylesheets generated by the CMS.

The CMS has a MySQL database, too, and if possible I would like the remote Testing server to run a mysqldump and compress/save the output into the repo before it is committed and pulled, so I can load it into my local testing server to bring it up to date.

So far I've been toying with hooks but I cannot find one that matches my needs. I was wondering if there is an idiomatic Mercurial way to go about this or if I should spend some time writing a shell script executing SSH commands remotely.

Comment: Normally CMS shouldn't generate anything that is a good candidate to be placed to a repository in runtime.

Comment: If the designer uploads a new logo or product image of a website we're working on, or changes the content of a page stored in the DB, how else can I pull those changes back down to the local environment so that tweaks I'm making to modules and stylesheets can account for them? I could use rsync and a hacked-together logging system, but Mercurial does this all for me. I realize this might be bad practice for some uses of an RCS, but this doesn't seem to be one of those uses.

Comment: mercurial is for code, for data you should do a backups: database, users' data, etc. It is one of those uses.

Comment: Perhaps you are referring to the difficulty hg has with large binary files? These are all typically smaller (<1MB) files, so that is not a concern here. These websites are fairly small, themselves, so the compressed DB is rarely more than >2MB, either.

If you're developing a website based on a CMS, the distinction between code and data becomes blurry. Additionally, I think you'll find that many of the tools you use have more than one use if you're a little creative (e.g. using m4 to generate host-specific configs from a template for a small group of hosts).

Comment: no, I'm referring to the difference between source code and users' data. That's it. Well, from your point of view it's a "creativity", from mine - adding an irrelevant garbage to the repository. "the distinction between code and data becomes blurry" --- it's pretty clear. What users upload is users' data.

Comment: Then what about what I upload? A lot of these images are required for the website to display properly, ultimately, as well. And the copy in the pages and the templates I write to customize the CMS for the client. So are you saying that (only the code) files unzipped from the install tarball and (the code) of the modules I write should be the only things in the repo? Because that's silly. It makes sense if I'm a developer of the CMS, but I'm getting that from a tarball and my modules are in subrepos. I'm making a website, not a CMS. The "data" is the vast majority of content in this repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0 You must to have Mercurial on the Testing

1. You must have Mercurial repository on the Testing (`hg init`)
2. You must convert your application on the Testing into Working Directory of server's repository (`hg add...` + edit .hgignore + ...)
3. You have to have cron-job (or sheduler-task) on Testing, which 1) test state of wd, and, if local modifications found, commit (maybe with dump, prepared by the same job earlier)
4. After all you can just pull from Testing's repo

Comment: I had toyed with a similar solution, but it still means relying on a cron job and setting up a framework so it runs on all existing projects and dealing with security or usability concerns. It also means waiting a minute or two after a known change to pull it down. These aren't really acceptable to me when I could just use SSH to sent a remote commit command if it comes down to using outside (non-hg) tools and avoid those drawbacks.

Comment: @alexanderfb - ok, you can (instead of cron) use FAM-module for auto-commiting changes ASAP, or commit from .bashrc( or .*whatever*rc on login to Testing). But anyway, re-think about MySQL sync-process - I'll suggest to think about Liquibase

Comment: I didn't think of using *rc, but that just might work with a little figuring. And Liquibase looks brilliant just from a quick glance over. I might be able to work with this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to to execute a remote command to run a commit on the server side.

```
--remotecmd CMD  specify hg command to run on the remote side
```

Comment: You are **totally wrong** in the assuming of --remotecmd purpose

Comment: Please explain.  I cannot find much info about it.

Comment: [Mercurial, SSH, and a local install](http://bitworking.org/news/350/ssh-mercurial-local-install) - latest paragraphs near the bottom, starting from "Then I need to specify the exact location of hg from the command line on the laptop..."